# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 beta?

Tags: upgrade, 20.10

I see this [Call for Beta Testing Ubuntu 21.04 and Ubuntu Flavours](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-beta-testing-ubuntu-21-04-and-ubuntu-flavours/21636) message and I would like to test this version on my sandbox Linux Desktop (I have another Laptop for work tasks).

I see this old AskUbuntu question [How to upgrade to a beta version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538937/how-to-upgrade-to-a-beta-version) but as I mentionned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538937/how-to-upgrade-to-a-beta-version#comment2265474_538945) « Software & Updates dialog box doesn't contain "Pre-released updates" option any more »

Question: what is the mainstream process to upgrade Ubuntu from `20.10` to `21.04 beta`?

Comment: "doesn't contain "Pre-released updates" option any more " yes it does. see the developer tab

Comment: Next to that: it got closed due to https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1 Your question is still a duplicate against that one We do not need a topic like this for every release. if you have a new method please answer the topic in this comment

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your question will be on-topic here).

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe the good methods are:

- via GUI: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `update-manager -d`
- via command line: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

For this two methods, it is `-d, --devel-release` option which means update to development version.